# Clean code structure for dynamically rendering strings & numbers

Tags: c++, architecture, rendering

I am currently working on the rendering aspect of my game.
The code is currently organized in this manner:

Classes:
G_Texture:

```
class G_Texture
{
public:
    G_Texture();
    G_Texture(SDL_Texture*);

    ~G_Texture();

    virtual void render(SDL_Renderer*);
        //Render

    SDL_Rect dst; // Destination rectangle to render the texture

};
```

G_Text:

```
    class G_Text : public G_Texture
    {
    public:
        G_Text();
        G_Text(std::string, G_BitmapFont*);
        ~G_Text();

        G_BitmapFont*  font;
        std::string text;

        void render(SDL_Renderer* renderer);
    };


G_Image:

class G_Image : public G_Texture
{
public:
    G_Image();
    G_Image(SDL_Texture* text);
    ~G_Image();
    void render(SDL_Renderer*);

    SDL_Texture* texture; // Texture source
    SDL_Rect* clip; // Sub-section of texture to draw
    SDL_RendererFlip flip;
};
```

What I want to do now is add three features:
1) Dynamically changing string
I want to dynamically render a changing string. If for example I have a character in my game with a continuously changing name, what approach should I take to render that changing name?
Do I create a new class for dynamic string, which holds a string pointer?

2) Dynamically changing number
So this is the same as (1), except now I want to update a number (int, double, etc...) into a string. Do I create a new class specifically for holding an int pointer? I feel like making all these classes wouldn't be very elegant. If I wanted to display anything other than an int I would have to make a new class...

3) Dynamically changing image width (Ex health bars)
If I want to create a health bar whose size depends on the health of a character, what is the best approach. My current thought is to create another class for health bars, which would have a pointer to the character. Once again this doesn't seem very elegant or reusable, as I would have to create new classes for each different component requiring different pointers.

I apologize if this is confusing. I'm new to game development and stack exchange.

Comment: It would greatly help if you provided sample code so we can see the alternatives :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two significant issues that I'd like to point out with your approach. One is separating concerns; the other is retaining state.

First, `G_Texture` is a resource class. It links a file in the filesystem to a representation of a texture in memory.

If you look at the example `G_Texture` class you have proposed, what does `render` do? Does it draw the whole texture at a given coordinate on the screen? Can you pick a part of the texture to render? Can you rotate or scale it? You picked some default behavior for `G_Texture::render`, and while you picked a reasonable and common behavior, it's arbitrary. What does it mean to render a texture, when a texture can be used so many ways?

What I'm saying is that your `G_Texture` class should be responsible for holding onto an `SDL_Texture *` and destroying it at the right time, and that's it. There are lots of ways to use a texture; don't pick one and stick it in the class and then override it in lots of confusing ways in other classes. Let other classes *use* a texture however they want to. Maybe they use two textures. Maybe they use a texture and a text file (a list of frames in an animation).

`G_Text` and `G_Image`, and e.g. `G_DynamicString`, `G_DynamicNumber`, `G_ResizeableImage` are all behavior classes. They describe special ways to draw a `G_Texture`. They could inherit from an interface, `G_Renderable`, instead of `G_Texture`.

I think you're finding this subclassing messy because you see that the "is-a" relationship isn't right. `G_Text` is not a special case of `G_Texture` -- rather, it uses a texture. What if your `G_Text` requires multiple images for all the glyphs? What if you want a `G_ResizeableAnimatedImage`?

A better approach is a "has-a" relationship. The classes that define behaviors have a reference (or a shared pointer, or a resource handle) to the resources that they need.

There are lots of different ways to work with textures, like most resources. If you separate resources and behaviors, by

- making the resource "just a container" that is concerned with its own lifecycle -- handling its own creation/destruction and properties (width, height), and
- making other classes that accept resources and know how to do things (e.g. draw text)

your code will be easier to work with in the long run.

Now, retaining state:

A game fills the screen every frame, and the contents of the screen are thrown away. The game doesn't know or care whether a string is dynamic or static; at some level, a graphics API still has to say "draw this string" every frame.

There are definitely optimizations to be made, but I don't really understand your distinction between "Text" and "DynamicString" at this point. If you have a class that knows what to do when you call `setText`, that covers both cases. Since you mentioned a pointer, I am guessing that you want to pull the game data in, every frame; a simplistic way to do this would be to supply a method that takes a lambda `const string&(){}`. That function can pull data from anywhere and you can make it take an integer, a string or whatever else from the closure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you,
I am not sure I understand everything (I'm not exactly the most advanced programmer)

_"A better approach is a "has-a" relationship. The classes that define behaviors have a reference (or a shared pointer, or a resource handle) to the resources that they need. If you separate resources and behaviors your code will be easier to work with in the long run."_
I don't really understand this part. What do you mean by separating resources and behaviour?

Comment: Elaborated on is-a (inheritance) vs has-a (composition), and tried to clarify why none of the classes you proposed are special kinds of textures.